# D3 creating a selector from this inside each

Tags: d3.js

I would like to be able to place each data object (in this case 'moreData' array) inside a group element.  So in the very simplified example below I would end up with three groups with 2 or 3 circles inside.

I'm using the node D3 provides with 'this' in a call to each (second one) to construct a selector.
Although the first call to each is correct (console.log tells me so)... the selector I create is obviously not doing the right thing as its creating 5 circles outside the body element and the second console.log never reports the first element.

Here is a fiddle [simple use of this](http://jsfiddle.net/stocksp/z9X9e/)

From this simple data set of three objects:

data = [{'data':10, 'moreData':[1,2]}, {'data': 12, 'moreData':[3,4,5]},{'data':6, 'moreData':[7,8,9]}];

I expect and get three groups but no circles inside the groups.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var shapes = svg.selectAll("g")
                .data(data).enter();
shapes.append("g").each(add);
function add(d, i) {
    console.log(i, d);
    // this is where we go south!!
    d3.select(this).data(d.moreData).enter() // help with this!!
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
        return (i + 1) * 25;
    })
    .attr("cy", 10)
    .attr("r", 10)
    .each(function (d, i) {
        console.log(i, d); // this is not good!
    })
```

thanks for any insight into what I'm doing wrong....
The above fiddle shows no output, but if you inspect the 'results' tab you can see the correct empty groups and the circle elements outside the body tag ... at least in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the empty set of circles before setting the data.

Right now, you are calling:

```
d3.select(this).data(d.moreData)
```

Replace that line with:

```
d3.select(this).selectAll("circle").data(d.moreData)
```

The general d3 enter paradigm is select a group -> attach data to that group -> use enter/exit, where enter will run for each item in the group which has data, but no DOM element, and exit for each element which has a DOM element but no data.

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/z9X9e/1/)

Also, you should use different variables for `i` and `d` for your inner function, since right now they're the same as the variables on your outer function. (Perhaps use `function(D, I)` instead.)